# Need to move linux Debian from bigger harddrive to a smaller one

Tags: linux, partitioning

I installed Debian Squeeze on a 1.5 TB harddrive. But later found out that there is a smaller, 250 GB drive around here.

So, I need to move the installation (maybe around 40-50 GB in total) from bigger HD to a smaller one.

How this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short you just have to shrink you partition to a size inferior to your future drive and then use partimage/clonezilla to image the whole disk. After restoring it on the smaller drive you can expand the partition again if you will to fit exactly to the drive.

Comment: OK, I got your point. Can I do shrinking with gpartd?

Comment: Gparted supports shrinking partition, yes, but you have to make you filesystem supports it to as some of them don't (XFS and JFS for example), hopefully for you most of them do (ext2/3/4 ; reiserFS)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to shrink you partition to a size inferior to your future drive and then use partimage/clonezilla to image the whole disk.
After restoring it on the smaller drive you can expand the partition again if you will to fit exactly to the drive.

Gparted does support shrinking partition, but you have to make sure your filesystem itself supports it, as some of them don't: XFS and JFS for example.
Hopefully ext2/3/4 which are highly common support it.

ReiserFS can be shrunk too but note that it may take a few hours to complete, depending on the size of data to move to the beginning of the partition.

Answer (score 1):

Shadok, thank you very much.

I did it. Below is short description.

There was 1500 GB drive with 60 GB data and 7GB swap. Quite regular setup, ext3 system Linux Debian Squeeze.

I wanted to swap this big drive to a 250 GB drive.

1. I downloaded and burned The Parted Magic distro LiveCD. This
   distro contains Gparted (partition tool) and Clonezilla. Though I
   used only Gparted.
2. Connected both drives and booted from LiveCD.
3. Opened partition tool (Gparted) and shrinked the main partition
   on source drive from something 1500 GB to 100 GB. (It takes time).
   And there was swap partition, we will come back later.
4. Deleted all partitions from destination (250 GB) drive.
5. Copied and pasted data partition from source disk to destination disk. Applied changes.
6. Created extended partition on destination. Just a little
   bigger than actual swap partition and aligned it to right.
7. Moved swap from source to destination, into extended that partition, again
   with right alignment.
8. Shrinked extended partition to fully contain swap, without empty space. Applied changes.
9. Than enlarged main data partition from 100 GB to contain empty space of the disk.
   Applied changes.

So, basically, I just moved all partitions from drive to drive.

But then came problems with Master Boot Sector. Gparted didn't copy them. So:

1. I found the original disk from which I installed this Debian 6 version and reloaded from it into rescue mode. At this point I already disconnected source hard drive. So when I loaded rescue mode, there was only destination disk present.
2. There was an option of MBR repair. Entered into it.
3. Assigned data partition as a root partition and then selected "repair" (or similar) option.

That's it.

Comment: No problem :) A detail: I think your post would be better as an edit of your question rather than as an answer, if you have doubt ask on the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the old and the new drive in the computer.
2. Boot using Knoppix7 from a USB or CD drive.
3. Go to preferences and start `Gparted`
4. Create a partition table on the new drive
5. Select the old drive

   - right click on the 1st partition
   - select copy
6. Select new drive

   - select Paste on the empty partition
7. Copy all your partitions excepted the swap that you will create.
8. Use `dd` to copy the boot sector.

You are done!

Comment: How should the OP copy the boot sector with `dd`?